# Unable to activate Fabled Cave

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

This has never happened to me before in the game. I came in to hunt for shiny Zekrom again but I found that it was stuck on "A mysterious ring is floating in the air...".

I have a level 100 pokemon in my party, and I have not messed with the time on my 3DS, so what gives? I did just recently download the latest update to the game, could that have done it?

I'm not really sure what it is I did wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try beating Elite 4 again, it "resets" Legendary respawn in this case.

Comment: Good! I'll write it as answer then

Answer (score 1):

Try beating Elite 4 again, it "resets" Legendary respawn in this case.